# JavaScript : insertBefore trigger "NotFoundError: Node was not found"

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to insert a new element in my page using the [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method, but the following error is triggered : "NotFoundError: Node was not found".

I don't understand why it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parent-id')

let title = notification.getElementsByTagName('h3')[1]
let subtitle = createNodeBefore(parent, title, 'h4', 'Subtitle text')
```

And here is my `createNodeBefore()` function :

```
let createNodeBefore = (parent, node, type, text, id = false, className = false, style = false) => {

    let textNode = document.createTextNode(text)
    let element = document.createElement(type)

    element.className = className ? className : ""
    element.id = id ? id : ""
    element.style = style ? style : ""
    element.appendChild(textNode)

    parent.insertBefore(element, node)

    return element
}
```

When I do console log just before the `parent.insertBefore(element, node)` line, I can see the `parent`, the `element` and the `node`.

**Edit :** Add html

The html looks like this :

```
<article id="parent-id">
    <div>
       <h3>Some text</h3>
       <i>5th December 2018</i>
       <h3>My title</h3>
       <p>Content ...p>
        ...
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: can you provide your HTML please

Comment: Are you sure that you have minimum 2 h3 tags in your HTML? In case if you have only one h3 tag then change the code as `let title = notification.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0]`

Comment: I just add the html. There is 2 h3 elements, and I have no problem for seeing my elements when I do console.log()

Comment: What is **notification**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code expects the `article` element to be the parent node of the `h3` element but it is not - the `div` element is its parent. This change should fix the issue:

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parent-id').getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```